# Issues with multiple keep blocks in Prometheus relabel Config

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am trying to use relabel blocks to select metrics based on labels, I want to select all the metrics that have any one one below labels with the given values

```
- source_labels: [label1]
  action: keep
  regex: (test1)
- source_labels: [label2]
  action: keep
  regex: (test2)

# Other way
- source_labels: [label1, label2]
  action: keep
  regex: (test|test1)
```

But all my metrics are getting removed even with correct labels and also it's same with using two different source label blocks with same conditions, Is there any better way to do this?